# getting space at the last of table cell

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put the image and text side by side. i was unable to make the image size(height & width) dynamic to fit into table cell and somehow i'm getting the space and background color is not applying fully at the end of table as shown :
[image: End of the table]

and when i tried running it in codepen the color applied fully. do i missing anything ?

this is the snippet that i'm working on:

```html
<table align="center" border="0" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; background: #0b3f90 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;">
 <tbody>
  <tr style="width: 100%;">
   <td style="background: #ffffff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box; width: 10%; border: 1px solid rgb(0, 62, 117);">
    <img alt="Head_Icn" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/129/200/200.jpg?hmac=Y7ERTUfFi4RdOFkUcoOnX_xjWnsy4PA7pJkkFmaQt8c" style="padding: 3px 5px 2px; float: left; width: 46px; height: 50px;" />
   </td>
   <td style="width: 90%; text-align: left; font: normal normal 600 12px/20px Segoe UI; letter-spacing: 0px; color: #ffffff; opacity: 1; border: 1px solid rgb(0, 62, 117);">&nbsp;&nbsp;Core Principles</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I couldn't understand your question a bit. Where is the white space coming?

Comment: `background: #ffffff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;` remove this line and your code'll be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need width: 90%. My code is bellow.

```
<table align="center" border="0" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; background: #0b3f90 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="width: 100%;">
            <td style="background: #ffffff 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box; width: 10%;">
                <img alt="Head_Icn" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/129/200/200.jpg?hmac=Y7ERTUfFi4RdOFkUcoOnX_xjWnsy4PA7pJkkFmaQt8c" style="padding: 3px 5px 2px; float: left; width: 46px; height: 50px;" />
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: left; font: normal normal 600 12px/20px Segoe UI; letter-spacing: 0px; color: #ffffff; opacity: 1; border: 1px solid rgb(0, 62, 117);">&nbsp;&nbsp;Core Principles</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```